# newman: could not find "htmlextra" reporter , using newman as library

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

I am trying to use newman as library to run my collections.
I have added the same to package.json and i can see the same under my node_modules.
The code works fine on my local. On my local there is no global installation for newman or newman-html-extra.
But when i can deploy the same on a box and try to run the same it fails.
with error :

**newman: could not find "htmlextra" reporter
ensure that the reporter is installed in the same directory as newman
please install reporter using np**

On the box , i can see the same present in package.json and also folder for newman and htmlextra report is created under node_modules.
Can someone please help me understand what i am missing here.
Node local version : v18.0.0
Node box version : v18.19.1

Code :

```
 const newman = require('newman');
  newman.run(
    {
      collection: JSON.parse(collectionFileData),
      environment: JSON.parse(envFileData),
      insecure: true,
      reporters: ['htmlextra'],
      reporter: {
        htmlextra: {
          export: resultFilePath,
        },
      },
    },
    async function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return {
          error: false,
          status: `We encounterd problem while running the collection : ${collectionFileName} Error message is : ${err} `,
          code: 500,
        };
      }


**[* node_modules]$ ls -lrt | grep newman
drwxr-xr-x  5 * *   119 Mar 21 07:05 newman-reporter-htmlextra
drwxr-xr-x  6 * *  4096 Mar 21 07:05 newman
```

Comment: How have you install those both on the "box"? Do you get the same if you try and install/use a different reporter? Hate to say it but sometimes removing and reinstalling the modules together will work here. :/

Comment: Hey Danny , they get installed together as part of prebuild : prebuild": "npm ci --legacy-peer-deps"

Comment: [*@* *]$ npm root
/*/*/node_modules
[*@*]$ npm list | grep newman
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS

├── newman-reporter-htmlextra@1.23.1
├── newman@6.1.2

Comment: Does Newman run without a custom reporter?

Comment: Hey @DannyDainton yes it works with cli , json and html reporter. I tried different approaches to get it working but still the same error persists. Is it possible to generate a report similar to htmlextra by using any template with the default html reporter ? do you know of any such template ? I do not want to reinvent the wheel by writing a new template

Comment: I don't know what else is going on here for that environment, if this was a wider issue - I would have people flooding my reporters issues. The template wouldn't full work with the html reporter as it have a lot more functionality and helpers in the htmlextra.